# DB collation VS Column collation when INSERTing

Tags: sql-server, collation

I've create 2 demo DB's.

**Server Collation** - Hebrew_CI_AS

**DB1 Collation** - Hebrew_CI_AS

**DB2 Collation** - Latin1_General_CS_AS.

In DB2 I have one column with Hebrew_CI_AS Collation. I'm trying to insert Hebrew text into that column. The Datatype is `nvarchar(250)`.

This is the sample script:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (HebCol)
VALUES('1בדיקה')
```

When I run this on DB1, everything works fine.

[image]

On DB2, Although the column has Hebrew Collation, I get question marks instead of the Hebrew text.

[image]

Why is the result different if the collation is identical?

P.S:  I cannot add `N` before the text. In the real world an app is doing the inserts.

Comment: *"P.S: I cannot add N before the text. In the real world an app is doing the inserts."* Then get used to having `?` in your data... Or change collation of the database. A literal string will be interpreted in the collation of the database you are currently connected to, not the destination column's.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So what affect does column collation have?

Comment: Strings of different collations can't be compared without explicitly changing the collation of one of them, @Itai. This means that you would be able to compare values in your 2 databases without explicitly changing the collation of one, and thus the query would be SARGable. Though I personally find that often people will design the database with 2 columns; one in the database's collation and then a second in another one as a (persisted) computed column. The latter is then used when comparing to a database using a different collation, while the former is within the same database.

Answer (score 2):

When using literal strings the collation used is that of the database, *not* the destination column. As the collation of the database you are inserting into is `Latin1_General_CS_AS` then for the literal string `'1בדיקה'` most of the characters are outside of the code page of the collation; thus you get `?` for those characters as they are unknown.

As such there are only 2 solutions to stop the `?` appearing in the column:

1. Fix your application and define your literal string(s) as an `nvarchar` *not* a `varchar`; you are after all storing an `nvarchar` so it makes sense to pass a literal `nvarchar`.
2. Change the collation of your database to be the same as your other database, `Hebrew_CI_AS`.

*Technically there is a 3rd, which is use a UTF-8 collation if you are on SQL Server 2019, but such collations come with caveats that I don't think are in scope of this question.*